# extend yeoman build process to minify json

Tags: minify, gruntjs, yeoman

i'm looking for a way to extend the build process of yeoman with something to minify json files ... i found a npm package which can minify json files but it doesn't export any functions :/ anyone that knows how to integrate this into the yeoman build process?

https://npmjs.org/package/json-minify

kind regards,

Daan

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one liner to minify JSON in node.js: `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonStr));`

I threw together a grunt-minjson plugin. Install with `npm install grunt-minjson --save-dev`, add `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-minjson');` to your Gruntfile and configure like such:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  minjson: {
    compile: {
      files: {
        'all.min.json': ['jsonfiles/*.json']
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a link to the project: https://github.com/shama/grunt-minjson